# Angular 4 call directive method from component

Tags: angular, angular-directive, angular-components

i'm trying to build a structural directive that will change the parent DOM structure either invoked by using its selector (static) or by calling its public method(dynamic).

- Using the directive selector in a html template works fine without
  any issues.
- I'm trying to figure out if we an achieve the same without using it in template and by calling the directive method.

**my-directive.ts**

```
@Directive({ selector: '[sampleDirective]' })

export class SampleDirective {
    ...
   constructor(..) {
        this.customDirective();
     }
  }
customDirective() {
    console.log('Inside customDirective()');
}
```

**my-component.ts**

```
import { SampleDirective } from './my.directive';
...
@Component({
 selector: 'my-component',
 template: `<button (click)="click()"> Click Me </button>`
})
constructor() { }
..
click() {
  // call directive method here
}
```

I need this because i'm creating a generic solution to change the DOM structure of a component at runtime with help of a directive.

** *please ignore if there are any typo. sorry that i couldn't paste the complete code here*

Comment: its not going to be possible without having the directive in the template. What you want is more a helpermethod/class than a directive.

Comment: could you provide me an example.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

If there's no directive in the component template Angular won't process it. With `ng-container` tag you will not clutter template in any way. To get the directive then use `@ViewChildren/@ViewChild` to get the instance of the directive:

```
@Component({
 selector: 'my-component',
 template: `<button (click)="click()"> Click Me </button>
            <ng-container sampleDirective></ng-container>`
})
@ViewChildren(SampleDirective) dirs;
constructor() { }
..
click() {
   this.dirs.first.customDirective();
  // call directive method here
}
```

Comment: Thanks. can we do without the additional div element. However i didn't get the expected result even with the above solution.

Comment: you need to have the directive applied to some element. you can use `ng-container` instead of `div`, it's rendered as a comment. what do you mean you didn't get the expected result? what is `this.dirs.length`? when do you call the `click()`?

Comment: i've updated my question. please check and provide me if we can achieve the requirement.

Comment: @mperle, if there's no directive in the component template Angular won't process it. Why is the requirement to not use directive in the template? With `ng-container` tag you will not clutter template in any way

Comment: @mperle, any comment?

Comment: yes, i agree with your point. I achieved it with the help of a component and a service. And that is the only way i see to meet my requirement.

Comment: saved my life :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48266720/angular-directive-not-working-on-hidden-element

Comment: This works perfectly fine with the ng-container approach! Thank you @MaxKoretskyi

Answer (score 1):

For calling directive method from component, you could use `ViewChild` decorator to locate directive instance on the page. Then by using the same you could access directive all props.

```
@ViewChild(SampleDirective) directive;
constructor() { }
..
click() {
  // call directive method here
  this.directive.customDirective()
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried this solution. But, i got console error 'cannot read property customDirective of undefined'

Comment: @mperle can you tell me, where did you placed `sampleDirective`?

Comment: did you mean where the directive file is located or ?

Comment: @mperle well, I meant to say where you used directive on HTML?

Comment: no thats the problem here. I don't want to use it inside any  template. I want to call the method to make changes to dom. Is that possible ? I've updated the question.

Comment: @mperle I don't understand how directive can work, without keeping it on DOM. I guess you talking about service, which can be standalone and reusable. But still not sure what you're looking for..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153175/discussion-between-mperle-and-pankaj-parkar).